# Is it possible to install Google plugin to Eclipse 4.x?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I did not develop eclipse plugins before and I do not know how it goes but I am wondering since GPE is now open source, is it easy to recompile the [plugin source](http://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/source/browse/) to produce a version compatible with eclipse 4.1 or 4.2 or would it need someone with plugin development experience ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try the new update site: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2  (Ref: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/xUZStgMUXlw/u6HacNDLYagJ)

Comment: i could not get it. It is connecting to the server.

Answer (score 3):

Removed original answer, as it has become deprecated. Use seanf's answer with the new update site link.

Comment: If there is a compatibility layer between 3.7 and 4.1, why doesn't the plugin simply install ? It gives me error that only one version of the platform SDK can be installed either 3.7 or 4.1. .. Is there a way to get around this and have it installed ?

Comment: The fact the plug-in does not install means that somewhere there is a dependency of some core plug-in such as [3.6.0,4.0.0) where 4.0.0 is disallowed. This is usually a sound assumption (conservatively not saying we work in a later version), however in this case it should be a non-issue. In this case the offending plug-ins are to be edited, and then recompiled and repackaged. In general, it shouldn't need too much work to achieve this, but needs a bit of understanding of both Eclipse plug-in development and GPE, while needing some testing/experimenting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a step-by-step guide on how to install Google plugin on Eclipse Juno (release candidate). 
It can also be found at https://plus.google.com/110140945975184013033/posts/ePFpQZYhPQq

```
How to Install GWT Plugin for Eclipse on 3.8 or Juno:

1. Download zipped update site for 3.7 
   from http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip.html
2. Unzip content.jar; rm content.jar
3. Edit content.xml; change 
   <required namespace='org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu' 
       name='org.eclipse.platform.feature.group' range='[3.7.0,3.8.0)'/> 
   to 
   <required namespace='org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu' 
       name='org.eclipse.platform.feature.group' range='3.7.0'/>
4. jar cMf content.jar content.xml (zip won't work)
5. Install from local update site
```

Comment: yep, I tested with Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) Release Candidate 3

Comment: It did not work with me @Alex on Juno 4.2 RC3 ..Another user commented on the original post that it did not work with him either. Is there any possibility that you did more than that to get it working ?

Comment: Just tested with Juno 4.2 release and the procedure above works fine. Just make sure you unselect Android-related stuff in the list as it rely on ADT to be installed.

Comment: Well, the official 4.2 plugin can now be downloaded from Google Developers website, so this work-around is now deprecated. See also the updated accepted answer.